# Handling Fragment transitions: menu items from another fragment showing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have an app where I have 3 main screens.

1) Home

2) Grid View

3) Stream View

The flows I have are:

- You can go from Home View to Grid View
- You can go from Grid View to Stream View and visa versa
- When you want to go back from Stream or Grid View, you should land on the Home View.

Everything is fine when I use the menu options. I have the following code:

Home View to Grid View (add Home View to back stack)

```
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, gridFragment)
            .addToBackStack(gridFragment.getTag())
            .commit();
```

Grid to Stream (don't add Grid View to back stack). Stream to Grid View is similar.

```
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, streamFragment)
            .commit();
```

Grid to Home. Stream to Home is similar:

```
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
```

All of the above works fine. Now to handle the hardware back button on the device, I have the following method in my Activity.

```
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
      if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        if (GlobalState.getCurrentFragment().class.getSimpleName().equals(
                StreamFragment.class.getSimpleName())) {
            clearBackStackAndChangeFragment(HomeFragment.newInstance());
        } else if (GlobalState.getCurrentFragment().getClass().getSimpleName().equals(
                GridFragment.class.getSimpleName())) {
            clearBackStackAndChangeFragment(HomeFragment.newInstance());
        } else {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
      } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
      }
  }

  public void clearBackStackAndChangeFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    fm.popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
  }
```

When the user goes to from Home->Grid->Stream->...back and forth a few times...->Home through hardware back button, I run in to an issue where the top menu on the action bar has items from the Grid/Stream views getting added. Looks like I am doing something wrong in handling the fragment transactions.

1) What am I doing wrong?

2) Is there a simpler and cleaner way to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

U r using class.tostring() , this won't return class name instead some kind of object ID in string. So instead use 
class.getSimpleName().... This will give class name and your if's checks in code may work.

Also my suggestion is use view pager  with tabs instead of fragment transactions, as its more easy to handle and maintain.

Comment: Updated the question to use getSimpleName().